# Why does ExecuteScalar() return null when my return values aren't null?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, null

Trying to assign result from `SQL` procedure into variable in `C#`

I have a procedure that has an input and output parameter. 
input Parameter of inPara takes an int
Output parameter of outPara returns a bigint

When I test the procedure, neither the output parameter, nor the return value reads null. (because i made it return the out parameter. )

This means that the procedure is not the problem, but something in my `C#` is.

My connection string and all is working properly.

Code below:

```
SqlCommand c = new SqlCommand();

c.CommandText = "ProcedureName";
c.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
c.Connection = con; //this works, prev defined

// Something below is the problem:
c.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@inPara", 3));
SqlParameter outer = new SqlParameter("@outPara", SqlDbType.BigInt);
outer.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
c.Parameters.Add(outer);

object o = c.ExecuteScalar();

if (o != null) int i = (int) o;
```

but o is always coming to be ***null*** even though it shouldn't. Am I missing something?

As per suggestions in the comments, I am displaying my SQL server stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyStoredProcedure (@inPara int, @outPara bigint out )
AS
BEGIN

set @inPara = (Select A.ID from myTable A
INNER JOIN   
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY HT_ID DESC) AS 'RN', *
  FROM myTable) B  ON A.ID= B.ID
AND B.RN = outPara)

return @outPara


END
GO
```

The result of the join is a table with 5 rows and no null values. 
when outPara is between 1 and 5, it returns a value for @outpara

Comment: Are you sure that the procedure return a value instead of filling the output parameter?

Comment: What does your stored procedure look like?

Comment: It look that you want `"@outPara"` binding variable value

Comment: The problem is in the way you return data. If you want to use ExecuteScalar, you should not RETURN but instead simply SELECT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the way you return data. If you want to use ExecuteScalar, you should not RETURN but instead simply SELECT.

If you can't change the SP, but the code, the solution is to read parameter '@outPara' with ExecuteNonQuery().

Assign the `UpdatedRowSource` property of the SqlCommand object to `UpdateRowSource.OutputParameters` to indicate that data will be returned from this stored procedure via output parameters.

```
command1.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.OutputParameters;
command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

read the value as `command1.Parameters["@outPara"].Value;`

Comment: I could not remember how it was, indeed, this is the solution +1

Comment: This helped greatly. Thank you!